# Should I say "certain atom make/s molecules"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Should I refer to the word "certain" as a plural or singular?

This is an example of the answer's sequences:

> "Certain atoms make molecules."
>
> "Certain atoms make**s** molecules."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Certain**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/certain) refers to an object that is

> 2:  of a specific but unspecified character, quantity, or degree

that is, it is one (or more) of a group of things and the adjective must describe those things, which are plural. The verb must agree with that plural subject.  Thus the sentence becomes:

> Certain atoms **make** molecules.

As a chemistry teacher, I also have to point out that this sentence is incredibly vague in terms of its chemistry content.  In the strictest sense it's true, I suppose, but all atoms other than helium and neon make true molecules under the right conditions.  (Helium and neon can form polyatomic ions, excimers, and several molecule-like substances, but no stable ground state molecules, yet.)

Comment: The "atom" instead of atoms is a typo. I edited it.

Comment: I can assume that you as a chemistry teacher agree that a molecule is made of two atoms at least. But I'd like to use the opposite way to say it. It says, instead of talking about molecule>atoms, I'd like to use atoms > molecule.

Comment: @Assiduous Sure, that's definitely true.  To be clear, you're saying that instead of something like "Molecules are made of a collection of atoms." you want to say "Atoms can bond/combine to make molecules."  In that sense your sentence, as written, is entirely correct; it's just quite broad.  That may be your intent though. :-)

Comment: I thought now on other option: "Certain atoms together make a molecule". What do you think now is better?

Comment: @Assiduous I would make it more explicitly focused on the chemistry, which when discussing atoms and molecules is going to center on the bonds that are formed among the atoms.  Perhaps "Certain atoms bind together to make a molecule."  I'd need the entire context of the sentence to really give you any better advice than that.

Comment: The entire context is about the building blocks of the life. certain atoms make molecule and then certain molecules make organelle which certain of them make the cell etc.

Comment: Well, it's not wrong, I can tell you that much.  It's entirely possible that it could be improved stylistically, but the sentence does make sense and fits with the idea you're going for.

Comment: Thank you for your help and advice. By the way, how could it be improved stylistically?

Comment: @Assiduous I would add more detail and try to be more specific about the topic.  "Certain" is a vague descriptor; if you're trying to say that only a few atoms (C,H,O,N, perhaps) combine to form organic molecules, then try to state that more clearly.  Again, you may *want* to state what you're saying without much specificity.  "Atoms of a small number of elements bind together to form molecules.  Those molecules can be assembled into organelles, and those organelles together form a cell."

Comment: Actually I didn't want to enter to the quantities issues, because molecule can be made of 2 atoms or even thousands atoms. Isn't?

Comment: Yes, I was talking about the number of varieties of atom rather than the absolute number of individual atoms involved.  A large molecule can have thousands of atoms but most biomolecules contain almost exclusively those four elements.

Comment: As you know, I talked about atoms rather than elements.

Comment: As I said before, without knowing the full context of this sentence/paragraph it's difficult to say much about it.  I trust that you know what you're trying to write and will do so appropriately.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit ambiguous; is the phrase *certain atom* meant to be replaced with the name of an atom? Or is it missing a preceding indefinite article ("a")?

Either way, this is a matter of verb conjugation, i.e. making the verb agree with the subject. In this case: *I make, you make, he/she/it makes, we make, they make*

Since the atom is the subject and it is singular, "atom" will take the "it" form of the verb, and hence become *Certain atom make**s***.

However, if you want to structure the sentence like this:

> A helium atom [...]

then it would be best to use the future tense:

> A helium atom **will make** [...]

Comment: There was a typo there. and it should be "certain atoms make/s molecule" instead of "certain atom make molecule"

Comment: OK, then you would use the "they" form of "make"; hence, *Certain atoms (will) make molecules.*